# How to get an array inside of an object from findOne Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am working with NodeJS and Mongoose. I have an object in MongoDB like this:

```
{
   "loc": "idexample",
   "a": ["1","2","3"],
   "b": ["4","5","6"]
}
```

I want to get the value of the key "a" in array format, not in an object.

I am doing this:

```
element.findOne({loc: "idexample"}, function(err,doc){
   console.log(doc.a); //Here I am getting an object like: 1,2,3 but I want an array, like this: ["1","2","3"]
});
```

The result is an object. I want an array. What can I do??

Comment: I cant even replicate the error using your exact code. doc.a returns `["1","2","3"]` for me

Comment: Sorry O'Dane Brissett, you are right, I confused miself. Thank you.